# Adding a regression trend line and a shaded standard error area to a ggplot for regression models that geom_smooth does not handle

Tags: r, ggplot2, glm, standard-error

I have a `data.frame` with observed success/failure outcomes per two groups along with expected probabilities:

```
library(dplyr)
observed.probability.df <- data.frame(group = c("A","B"), p = c(0.4,0.6))
expected.probability.df <- data.frame(group = c("A","B"), p = qlogis(c(0.45,0.55)))
observed.data.df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(c("A","B"), function(g)
  data.frame(group = g, value = c(rep(0,1000*dplyr::filter(observed.probability.df, group != g)$p),rep(1,1000*dplyr::filter(observed.probability.df, group == g)$p)))
)) %>% dplyr::left_join(expected.probability.df)

observed.probability.df$group <- factor(observed.probability.df$group, levels = c("A","B"))
observed.data.df$group <- factor(observed.data.df$group, levels = c("A","B"))
```

I'm fitting a logistic regression (`binomial` `glm` with a `logit` `link` `function`) to these data with the `offset` term:

```
fit <- glm(value ~ group + offset(p), data = observed.data.df, family = binomial(link = 'logit'))
```

Now, I'd like to plot these data as a bar graph using `ggplot2`'s `geom_bar`, color-coded by `group`, and to add to that the trend line and shaded standard error area estimated in `fit`.

I'd use `stat_smooth` for that but I don't think it can handle the `offset` term in it's formula, so looks like I need to resort to assembling this figure in an alternative way.

To get the bars and the trend line I used:

```
slope.est <- function(x, ests) plogis(ests[1] + ests[2] * x)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(observed.probability.df, aes(x = group, y = p, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  stat_function(fun = slope.est,args=list(ests=coef(fit)),size=2,color="black") +
  scale_x_discrete(name = NULL,labels = levels(observed.probability.df$group), breaks = sort(unique(observed.probability.df$group))) +
  theme_minimal() + theme(legend.title = element_blank()) + ylab("Fraction of cells")
```

[image]

So the question is how to add to that the shaded standard error around the trend line?

Using `stat_function` I am able to shade the entire area from the upper bound of the standard error all the way down to the X-axis:

```
ggplot(observed.probability.df, aes(x = group, y = p, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  stat_function(fun = slope.est,args=list(ests=coef(fit)),size=2,color="black") +
  stat_function(fun = slope.est,args=list(ests=summary(fit)$coefficients[,1]+summary(fit)$coefficients[,2]),geom='area',fill="gray",alpha=0.25) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = NULL,labels = levels(observed.probability.df$group), breaks = sort(unique(observed.probability.df$group))) +
  theme_minimal() + theme(legend.title = element_blank()) + ylab("Fraction of cells")
```

[image]

Which is close but not quite there.

Any idea how to subtract from the shaded area above the area that's below the lower bound of the standard error? Perhaps `geom_ribbon` is the way to go here, but I don't know how to combine it with the `slope.est` `function`